# RDLC Multiple Values on a Row

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, reporting, rdlc

Recently I began to use RDLC report, and I have some issues, how can I get a tablix of this way? ..

### Column

Description

Item 1    |  Item 2    |   Item 3   |    Item 4

I have an Object that populate the Tablix

I got a description, a type, and multiple items, but I don't know how can I get it in that way..

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to get focus of your "Table" (Tablix) (when added from the Toolbox) in the designer, go to the "DataSetName" property.  It will do a drop-down of the available data sources associated with your report.  Pick whichever table (or other enumerable list that has your data) as the source.

Then, you can put textbox controls IN that Tablix as associated to the "source" you've selected.  When running the report, it will do a detail row for each entry in your table/list.

The "Table" (Tablix)  Also has a header area where you can put other labels and heading things for the data.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I didn't explain fine, what I searching for, is that in one column of the Tablix  I can represent multiple cells on a row in a horizontal way.. like Item 1 |  Item 2   | Item 3

Comment: @user1088189, then you will probably have to update your data into a single row per however many you expect, such as 4 per row and build your reporting data that way.  From SQL, it would be considered a cross-tab to do such a build out.